# What's wrong with this sed?

Tags: linux, sed

For input:

```
ADAMS, Andrew 1234
BAYES, Ryan 9292
```

Inside `people.txt` , I used:

```
cat people.txt | sed 's/\([A-Z]+\),[[:space:]]+\([A-Z]\)\([a-z]+\).*/(\2) \2\3 \1/'
```

And expected to get:

```
(A) Andrew ADAMS
(R) Ryan BAYES
```

But instead, it printed the input again. What's wrong?

Comment: `\+` not `+`. Or use extended regular expressions, `sed -e`.

Comment: `awk` version: 

`awk '{gsub(/,/,"",$1);print "(" substr($2,0,1)")", $2,$1}' file`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F '[,[:blank:]]+' '{printf( "(%s) %s %s\n", substr($2,1,1), $2, $1}' people.txt

# alternative sed
sed 's/\([^[:blank:]]*\),[[:blank:]]*\(\(.\)[^[:blank:]]*\).*/(\3\) \2 \1/' people.txt
```

`cat | sed` is not needed for sed (maybe it's only for sample purpose in this OP)

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
sed 's/\(^.\)\([a-z]*\),\s*\([a-z]*\)\(.*$\)/(\1) \3 \1\2/gi' temp
```

Using the i at the end allows you to ignore case sensitivity

Using an asterisk is the shorter equivalent of backslash +

using backslash s is shorter equivalent for [[:space:]]

It also removes the unnecessary use of the cat command.